# How to pass token from client and get on Web API post method with form data?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a Web API where I need to submit form data but before submitting I need to check, user is authenticated or not. So, I am using token based authentication with angularjs client and saving token in localstorage.

But I don't have idea how to pass my token with form data which is stored in localstorage and get it on Post Method of controller as following.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Customer cust)
{
    var newCust = _Repository.InsertCustomer(cust);
    if (newCust != null)
    {
       **// need to get token here which is saved in local storage**

        return Created<Customer>(Request.RequestUri + newCust.ID.ToString(), newCust);
    }
    else
    {
        return Conflict();
    }
}
```

Please provide the solution with code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token from local storage using the key which you used to store like

```
var token = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("tokenKey"));
```

And then set the token in the request header

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.common['Authorization'] = token;
```

and in webapi controller get the token from header

```
IEnumerable<string> tokens;
var hastoken = Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out tokens);
```

However this is just simple implementation for understanding, you should search more and follow standard practices as per your application design.